# Do jquery button events in MVC 3 have a built-in mechanism that prevent ajax calls from functioning in parallel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I've got 2 jquery button events making their own ajax calls back to the server.  However, when I click on the first button and then click on the second button before the first makes the round trip back to "success" in its own ajax call, the second ajax call (through the second button) fails to make a connection to the server and calls the "error" handling in its own ajax call.  Is this intended behavior?  Is there a built-in mechanism for button click events that forces ajax calls to happen serially?  I'd appreciate the help!  NOTE:  I'm using MVC 3, btw.

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '@Url.Action("getExecAvgDaysToClose")',
       error: function (xhr, status, err) {
           alert("An error occurred between server and browser: " + err);
       },
       success: function (response) {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);
          var options = {
              width: gaugeWidth, height: gaugeHeight,
              redFrom: @Model.ChartConfig.ExecStatusRedFrom, redTo: @Model.ChartConfig.ExecStatusRedTo,
              yellowFrom: @Model.ChartConfig.ExecStatusYellowFrom, yellowTo: @Model.ChartConfig.ExecStatusYellowTo,
              greenFrom:@Model.ChartConfig.ExecStatusGreenFrom, greenTo: @Model.ChartConfig.ExecStatusGreenTo,
              greenColor: defaultGreenColor,
              yellowColor: defaultYellowColor,
              redColor: defaultRedColor,
              max: @Model.ChartConfig.ExecStatusMax,
              minorTicks: 3
          };
         var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('eAveDaysClose'));

    doDrawChart(chart, data, options);

   }
```

});

Comment: Nope, that should not be a problem. Maybe it's your server? What's the error message?

Comment: No, the two should work independently of each other.

Comment: I'm using MVC 3, if that helps.  The second ajax call always fails.  I wonder if there's something with MVC 3 that might be preventing the second call.

Comment: Or, perhaps, the IIS configuration on the server...

Comment: The error message is basically the error handling in the ajax call:  "An error occurred between server and browser."  Essentially, the ajax call fails for the second call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be due to `ASP.NET Session State`. I believe that all requests made from the *same session* are serialized and run concurrently by default, not in parallel. This includes ajax requests. Otherwise a Session could be corrupted if a controller attempts to write to Session while another controller is accessing it.

In MVC 3 you can workaround this by adding `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` to your controller. Here's some information on [session less controllers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/12/17/session-less-mvc-controller.aspx?Redirected=true) Asynchronous controllers might be another workaround.